# Same code returns different results from different runs

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Im my code, there is a dataframe I created from a hive table. And I do a simple filter with the fonction filter. But the result is random : I execute the same cell containing the filter several times, sometimes, it returns the line, sometimes it doesn't return. I'm sure that there is only one line in the expected result. And no other works at the same time on the source file.

```
df = spark.sql("select id from hive_table limit 100")

df.filter(col('id') == 27654909)
```

Comment: This could be an issue with the way the dataframe is setup. Could you provide the scheme/structure?

Comment: It's the LIMIT who cause the 'problem', see my commentary below.

Comment: Makes sense. I just wasn't sure if id was the same as the index or an arbitrary id set by you. Glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert in pyspark, *to be sure*, but your symptoms sound like *limit* is actually controlling the *depth* of the search and *not* the maximum number of record results to return.

Since I imagine this is in a dev environment, if you remove the limit clause, do you get success 100% of the time?

Comment: It's well the LIMIT who returns the number of lines randomly. It's the spec of spark about limit:  limit(num)[source]

    Limits the result count to the number specified.                                                                I test 'order by' a column then limit, it returns always the same result.                                 df = spark.sql("select id from hive_table order by id limit 100")

Comment: Ah, m'kay. Then you should mark your reply as the answer, since you have a work-around. I'd chase the Spark community for further assistance on debugging the undesired behaviour that you're seeing.